# How do I get Virtual Box to access an IP other than default localhost

Tags: virtualbox

So I know to access my host computer's localhost from virtualbox, I can hit up the IP 10.0.2.2.  However, I need to access a different IP on my host.  I've set up another local site running on host at 192.168.7.9.  How do I hit this IP from inside virtualbox?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual machine is probably in NAT networking mode.
You need to change networking to Bridged and choose the same Network adapter
like i did on the image below...(on my laptop wifi NIC is Intel Centrino, yours is probably different!)
Then your virtual machine will be directly connected to the same network as your laptop and it'll have a similar IP address as your host... 192.168.7.x
and then you can connect to any IP address you want!

This would be the simplest way to do it.

[image]